# Jquery get the custom response content when I do an ajax and return an error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http-status-code-500

I am doing a classing ajax ger request:

```
$.get('/ajax').done(function(data){
   //handle data on success
}).fail(function(jqXHR,status,errorThrown){
    if(jqXHR.status===500){
       //Handle response there
    }
})
```

I want somehow to be able to get the custom response when my endpoint to ajax request returns error `500`.

Comment: Note on the duplicate `error` is your proper `fail` with the same parameters passed back.  jqXHR here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `$.get` has `.error` method. See here, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/#jqxhr-object

Instead, you need to handle the error inside the .fail

If you really want to handle using .error then do `$.ajax` instead

Comment: That's correct it was a typo and I fixed my question

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Why is jqXHR.responseText returning a string instead of a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825465/why-is-jqxhr-responsetext-returning-a-string-instead-of-a-json-object#11595709) you can get the response data when an error occurs using:

```
$.get('/ajax').done(function(data){
   //handle data on success
}).fail(function(jqXHR,status,errorThrown){
    if(jqXHR.status===500 && jqXHR.responseText){
      console.err(jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: what is `jxqr`, it is not defined anywhere?

Comment: fixed the mentioned typo